# Context bounds for polymorphic function type in Scala3?

Tags: scala, generics, lambda, polymorphic-functions

## **The set up:**

I'm somewhat new to Scala (specifically, Scala 3) - so I understand that the following question might be dumb/naïve.

I know that a polymorphic method type below works.

```
def zeroMethod[A:Numeric] = Numeric[A].zero
```

Here Numeric is the context bound on the generic type A.

Notice that
`scala> zeroMethod[Int]`
yields `val res0: Int = 0`.  Or with the help of type inference:

```
scala> val a = zeroMethod[Int]
val a: Int = 0
```

A slight extension of this is

```
def zeroMethodFromVal[A:Numeric](x : A) = Numeric[A].zero
```

The only real use that the argument `x` supplies is that it facilitates type-inference.

Specifically,

```
scala> zeroMethodFromVal(5)
val res1: Int = 0
```

From there, I wanted to write a polymorphic function type that mirrored the behavior of the polymorphic method type.

How can you add context bounds to polymorphic function types?  Or is it just not possible since the context bounds are simply syntactic sugar for passing implicit arguments?

When I attempt to make a function-equivalent to `zeroMethod`, it gives me all sorts of errors ... some that depart from the topic at hand.  Thus, I will omit that particular code-snippet.  However, it seems like it should be feasible to make a function-equivalent to `zeroMethodFromVal` and that doesn't distract from the topic at hand.

Specifically, my (first) attempt was:

```
val zeroFunFromVal : [A:Numeric] => A => A = [A:Numeric] => (x: A) => zeroMethodFromVal[A](x)
```

This fails, producing a syntax error.  It doesn't like the added context bound to the generic.
Of course, if I try to eliminate the context bounds altogether, then I obviously get a type error, because `zeroMethodFromVal` doesn't receive the implicit that it requires (i.e. the context bounds aren't being enforced on the generic).

Is there a way to get this polymorphic function type to work like the polymorphic method type? (that includes the context bounds?)

Comment: Context bound is just sugar syntax on top of `using` parameters _(which shouldn't exist nor be used IMHO, but that is another discussion)_. And using parameters is a concept that only methods can have, not functions. - However, there is a new special kind of function in **Scala 3**, [_context functions_](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/contextual/context-functions.html) which are essentially functions with `using` parameters.

Answer (score 5):

With Scala 3, the syntax to define implicit parameters in function declaration is `ImplicitType ?=> ...`.

In your case, the following works:

```scala
val zeroFunFromVal: [A] => A => Numeric[A] ?=> A =
  [A] => (x: A) => (evA: Numeric[A]) ?=> zeroMethodFromVal[A](x)(evA)

val five: Int = 5
zeroFunFromVal.apply(five) // Gives 0
```

Comment: Your reply had the ingredients I needed/wanted.  Your code didn't exactly work in my scala-REPL ... giving me the error:   `Ambiguous given instances: both object BigDecimalIsFractional in object Numeric and object LongIsIntegral in object Numeric match type Numeric[A] of parameter x$1 of method apply`.  The error arose just because the use of the given was in the first argument place.  When I moved the implicit argument to the end, it worked!  Here's what I used:  `val zeroFunFromVal: [A] => A => Numeric[A] ?=> A = [A] => (x:A) => (evA: Numeric[A]) ?=> zeroMethodFromVal[A](x)(evA)`.

Comment: With my slight alteration of your suggestion, the function-call is a little cleaner too ...  `zeroFunFromVal(5) // Gives 0, as it should`

Comment: Also, your recommendation gave me the required insight on how to write the function version of zeroMethod.  There it's just:  `val zeroFun: [A] => Numeric[A] ?=> A = [A] => (evA: Numeric[A]) ?=> zeroMethod[A](evA)`.  The call then is just: `val x = zeroFun[Int] // Gives 0`

Comment: Good catch on the order of parameters.